# eAccelerator lead to apache Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, eaccelerator

I don't know why the apache child process regularly exit with signal Segmentation fault (11).

php Version 5.2.5,eAccelerator 0.9.5.3。
When enabling Caching in eAccelerator　extension and doing stress test, apache always exit whit error log:

[notice] child pid 29237 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
sometimes there is another error log:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47645029712760 bytes) in Unknown on line 0。

Using gdb to trace the segmentation fault，I get the context:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x53c95b0, p=0x2b5538df1f58) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1944
#1  0x00002b553214e718 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x5395ec0) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_hash.c:526
#2  0x00002b553214368f in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0x5395e98) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_variables.c:43
#3  0x00002b5532137116 in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x5395ff0) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#4  0x00002b553214e988 in zend_hash_clean (ht=0x5395df0) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_hash.c:552
#5  0x00002b553216435c in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7fff7210ac30) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:255
#6  0x00002b553216382c in execute (op_array=0x5395b18) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:92
#7  0x00002b55321439ad in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=<value optimized out>, file_count=3) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/Zend/zend.c:1134
#8  0x00002b553210103b in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fff7210d100) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/main/main.c:2005
#9  0x00002b55321c3ba5 in php_handler (r=0x53d7d08) at /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/php-5.2.5/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:631
#10 0x0000000000443c9c in ap_run_handler ()
#11 0x0000000000444541 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#12 0x000000000048336c in ap_process_request ()
#13 0x000000000047ff71 in ap_process_http_connection ()
#14 0x000000000044d2ce in ap_run_process_connection ()
#15 0x000000000044d641 in ap_process_connection ()
#16 0x00000000004a26e7 in child_main ()
#17 0x00000000004a288d in make_child ()
#18 0x00000000004a2aff in perform_idle_server_maintenance ()
#19 0x00000000004a2fe2 in ap_mpm_run ()
#20 0x000000000042a93f in main ()
```

It sames have nothing relationship with EA，but when I disable Caching in EA，it sames work fine, Segmentation disppeared。

the php script is very simple:

```
function test($option = array('dfii12dfdfdfdfdfdf' => 0))
{
     return 'asdfasdfasdfais';
}
echo test();
```

After excuting the  test function, zend will free "$option" hash table，at that time，the segmentaion happened。

```
(gdb) p *ht->pListHead 
$8 = {h = 14664090660519840576, nKeyLength = 19, pData = 0x5395f80, pDataPtr = 0x2b5538df1f58, pListNext = 0x0, pListLast = 0x0, pNext = 0x0, pLast = 0x0, arKey = "d"}
```

the point pDataPtr is an invalid address。
I check the address by pmap，0x2b5538df1f58 mapped to /dev/zero

> 00002b5538def000 131072K rw-s-  /dev/zero (deleted)

Thank a lot。

Comment: Can you try the same test with lighttpd?

Comment: Does lighttpd support eAccelerator? The segmentaton problem only happen when enabing cacheing in eAccelerator。